# Knitr option hook results in LaTeX output

Tags: knitr

I'm creating ioslides and beamer output from RMarkdown source files and need to have variable figure output dependent on the output format.

I've generate a plot using `ggplot2` which renders fine.
I want the plot to have an `out.width` set to 100% for HTML output and 70% for LaTeX output.
The problem is that when I set the option hook and check for LaTeX output, the tex file generated by knitr contains the LaTeX source verbatim for including the image which renders as text in the slide.

```
## Modify the output based on the format we're exporting
knitr::opts_hooks$set (out.width = function (options) {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    options$out.width = '70%'
  }
  options
})
```

The plot renders fine in HTML output.
However, for beamer I get as shown in the image:
[image]

And the resulting output in the `.tex` file:

```
\begin{frame}{Why bother?}
\protect\hypertarget{why-bother}{}

\textbackslash begin\{center\}\textbackslash includegraphics{[}width=70\%    {]}\{slide-book\_files/figure-beamer/lec-4-modularity-cost-1\}
\textbackslash end\{center\}

\end{frame}
```

Here's complete code for a MWE:

```
## Modify the output based on the format we're exporting
knitr::opts_hooks$set (out.width = function (options) {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    options$out.width = '70%'
  }
  return (options)
})
```

````
```{r, lec-4-modularity-cost, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align='center'}

plot.data <- tibble (X = seq (0,100), Y = 2 * X)

ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_path()
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I've edited the question. Note if I flip it on its head, changing the plot chunk option to `out.width='100%'` and in the `opts_hooks` chunk check use `is_html_output()` setting `out.width='70%'` I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `out.width` this way you have to use a format that LaTeX understands right away, i.e. `0.7\linewidth` instead of `70%`. And you have to double the backslash in the R code:

````
---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
## Modify the output based on the format we're exporting
knitr::opts_hooks$set (out.width = function (options) {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    options$out.width = '0.7\\linewidth'
  }
  options
})

```

```{r, lec-4-modularity-cost, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align='center'}
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
plot.data <- tibble (X = seq (0,100), Y = 2 * X)

ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_path()
```
````